# Confusion in Integral, involving infinite limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I found the following question in a book -

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{1 + \sin \alpha \sin x}dx$$

Now, I understand that the correct approach of this would be -

[image: solution]

And then, just solving the simplified integral.

But, I was wondering what goes wrong when I do it this way, where I don't break the integral into two parts, one from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$.

[image: What just happened?]

Suddenly, the integral involves infinite limits. Shouldn't the answer come out the same with both the methods?

Comment: What is wrong with infinite limits ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai I am unable to solve it further.

Comment: Maybe you can use arctan ?

Comment: i think we must know something about $\alpha$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai - I'll try that.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - The answer is in terms of $\alpha$. You can treat it as a constant.